# Blackjack wins calculation error: counting too many hands

Tags: java, blackjack

I'm trying to code a Black Jack simulator program.  It asks a user for how many decks of cards to use and how many hands to simulate, as well as whether or not to show the outcome of each hand.  Then it runs the program based off of Black Jack strategy and is supposed to output accurate win/lose percentages.  However, when I run it, my player win count/dealer win count numbers are greater than the number of hands I wanted to play.

I think it's my push and split methods, but I'm unsure how to fix them.  Currently, my push method deals a new hand and determines the winner of the hand, then adds the push amount to the wins of either the player or dealer.  however, this treats it as a new hand within the loop for the current hand, therefore giving me an extra hand.  My split method works in a similar fashion.  Any suggestions for how I could rewrite them correctly would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Game
{
int decks                 = 4;
int hands                 = 1;
int myCardsSum            = 0;
int dealerCardsSum        = 0;
final int DECK_SIZE       = 52;
final int BLACKJACK       = 21;
String display;
boolean displayData       = true;
boolean myHardHand        = true;
boolean dealerHardHand    = true;
boolean doubleAllowed     = true;
boolean splitAllowed      = true;
boolean surrenderAllowed  = true;
Deck myDecks;
int myWins                = 0;
int dealerWins            = 0;
int push                  = 0;

Card myFirst;
Card mySecond;
Card dealerFirst;
Card dealerSecond;

// Input prompt removed
  // asks user for decks, hands, and display information

public void play()
{

    // A deck of cards made of all the decks selected by the user
    myDecks = new Deck(); 
    myDecks.setCardsInDeck(4 * decks);

    for (int i = hands; i > 0; i--)
    {
        deal();
    } 

    double winPercent    = (double) myWins / hands;
    double losePercent = (double) dealerWins / hands;
    // Output removed
}

public void deal()
{
        myHardHand           = true;
        dealerHardHand       = true;
        splitAllowed         = true;
        doubleAllowed        = true;
        surrenderAllowed     = true;

        myDecks.shuffle(decks); // shuffles if the deck is half empty or less

        myFirst    = myDecks.drawCard();
        mySecond = myDecks.drawCard();

        dealerFirst    = myDecks.drawCard();
        dealerSecond = myDecks.drawCard();

        myCardsSum     = myFirst.getCardVal() + mySecond.getCardVal();
        dealerCardsSum = dealerFirst.getCardVal() + dealerSecond.getCardVal();

        // Check for aces and assign either 1 or 11 as its value for the round
        if (myCardsSum <= 10 &&
                (myFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
                 mySecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
        {
            myCardsSum+= 10;
            myHardHand = false;
        }

        if (dealerCardsSum <= 10 &&
                (dealerFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
                 dealerSecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
        {
            dealerCardsSum+= 10;
            dealerHardHand = false;
        }

        if (myCardsSum == BLACKJACK && dealerCardsSum != BLACKJACK)
        {
            myWins++;
            // output removed
        }
        else if (myCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
        {
            dealerWins++;
            // output removed
        }
        else if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
        {
            // output removed
            push();
        }
        else
        {
            // output removed
            chooseMove(dealerFirst, myFirst, mySecond, myCardsSum);
        }
}

public void hit()
{
    doubleAllowed        = false;
    splitAllowed         = false;
    surrenderAllowed = false;

    Card draw = myDecks.drawCard();
    myCardsSum += draw.getCardVal();

    if (myCardsSum <= 10 &&
            draw.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
    {
        myCardsSum+= 10;
        myHardHand = false;
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > 21 &&
         (myFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
            mySecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
    {
        myCardsSum-= 10;
        myHardHand = true;
    }
    // output removed

    if (myCardsSum == BLACKJACK && dealerCardsSum != BLACKJACK)
    {
        myWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
    {
        dealerWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
    {
        // output removed
        push();
    }
    else
    {
        chooseMove(dealerFirst, myFirst, mySecond, myCardsSum);
    }

}

public void stand()
{
    // output removed

    while (dealerCardsSum < 17 || (dealerCardsSum == 17 && dealerHardHand == false))
    {
            Card draw = myDecks.drawCard();
            dealerCardsSum += draw.getCardVal();

            if (dealerCardsSum <= 10 &&
                    draw.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
            {
                dealerCardsSum+= 10;
                dealerHardHand = false;
            }
            else if (dealerCardsSum > 21 &&
                            (dealerFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
                             dealerSecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
            {
                dealerCardsSum-= 10;
                dealerHardHand = true;
            }
            //output removed
    } // End loop

    if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
    {
        // output removed
            push();
    }
    else if (dealerCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
    {
            // output removed
            myWins++;
    }
    else if (dealerCardsSum > myCardsSum && dealerCardsSum < BLACKJACK)
    {
            // output removed
            dealerWins++;
    }
}

public void push()
{
    push++;
    int score = myWins;

    deal();

    if (score < myWins) // if the player won the last round
    {
        myWins += push;
    }
    else
    {
        dealerWins += push;
    }

    push = 0;
}

public void surrender() // program does not keep track of bets; no half loss
{
    // output removed
    dealerWins++;
}

public void doubleDown() // program does not keep track of bets; no double gain
{
    doubleAllowed        = false;
    splitAllowed         = false;
    surrenderAllowed = false;

    Card draw = myDecks.drawCard();
    myCardsSum += draw.getCardVal();

    if (myCardsSum <= 10 &&
            draw.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
    {
        myCardsSum+= 10;
        myHardHand = false;
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > 21 &&
         (myFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
            mySecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
    {
        myCardsSum-= 10;
        myHardHand = true;
    }

    // output removed

    if (myCardsSum == BLACKJACK && dealerCardsSum != BLACKJACK)
    {
        myWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
    {
        dealerWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
    {
        // output removed
        push();
    }
    else if (myCardsSum < dealerCardsSum)
    {
        dealerWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else
    {
        myWins++;
        // output removed
    }
}

public void split()
{
    Card split1 = myDecks.drawCard();
    myCardsSum = myFirst.getCardVal() + split1.getCardVal();

    if (myCardsSum <= 10 &&
            split1.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
    {
        myCardsSum+= 10;
        myHardHand = false;
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > 21 &&
         (myFirst.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
            split1.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
    {
        myCardsSum-= 10;
        myHardHand = true;
    }
    // output removed

    if (myCardsSum == BLACKJACK && dealerCardsSum != BLACKJACK)
    {
        myWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
    {
        dealerWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
    {
        // output removed
        push();
    }
    else
    {
        chooseMove(dealerFirst, myFirst, split1, myCardsSum);
    }



    Card split2 = myDecks.drawCard();
    myCardsSum = mySecond.getCardVal() + split2.getCardVal();

    if (myCardsSum <= 10 &&
            split2.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
    {
        myCardsSum+= 10;
        myHardHand = false;
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > 21 &&
         (mySecond.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace") || 
            split2.getCardName().equalsIgnoreCase("ace")))
    {
        myCardsSum-= 10;
        myHardHand = true;
    }
    // output removed

    if (myCardsSum == BLACKJACK && dealerCardsSum != BLACKJACK)
    {
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum > BLACKJACK)
    {
        dealerWins++;
        // output removed
    }
    else if (myCardsSum == dealerCardsSum)
    {
        // output removed
        push();
    }
    else
    {
        chooseMove(dealerFirst, mySecond, split2, myCardsSum);
    }

}

public void chooseMove(Card dealers, Card first, Card second, int mySum)
{
  // switch determining which moves to make removed
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring "hands"?

Comment: With the rest of my global variables.  I initialize it to 1 but then get a value from the user between 1-1000

Comment: Have you tried doing 'hands--' at the start of push() and split() methods everytime you call them, to counteract the addition to hands that is made when you call these methods if that's where you say the problem is. In saying that I don't see where hand is being incremented anywhere in your code(the only reference to hand I see is when you declare it at the start).

Comment: I'm not actually ever changing "hands" after getting its value from the user.  I create a for loop where int i = hands and then use that to call the deal method for each hand played.